# Let $K=\Bbb Q (e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{7}})$ and $\alpha \in K - \Bbb Q$. Then show that, $\Bbb Q(\alpha)=K$

Tags: field-theory, cyclotomic-fields

> Let $K=\Bbb Q (e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{7}})$ and $\alpha \in K - \Bbb Q$. Then show that, $\Bbb Q(\alpha)=K$ .

My attempt:

I have computed the minimal polynomial of$e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{7}}$ over $\Bbb Q$ to be $x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 $ and thus, $[K:\Bbb Q]=6$

Since, $\alpha \in K - \Bbb Q$ , it follows that, $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ is a subfield of $K$ containing $\Bbb Q$, moreover, $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q] | [K:\Bbb Q] \implies [\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q] =$1 or 2 or 3 or 6 .Since, $\alpha \notin \Bbb Q$, $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q] \ne 1$ .

Since, for $\beta = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{7}}$, $\{1,\beta,\beta^2,\beta^3 ,\beta^4,\beta^5\}$ is a basis of $K$ over $\Bbb Q$. then, $\exists a_j \in \Bbb Q , 0\le j \le 5$ with at least one of $a_j \ne 0 $ for $j \ge 1$ so that, $\alpha=a_0 +a_1 \beta+\dots+a_5 \beta^5$ .

How to proceed with then proof. Thanks in advance for help!

Note that this question is also present in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443042/looking-at-the-intermediate-fields-of-bbbq-7-bbbq-omega-bbbq-wher), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463968/finding-the-intermediate-fields-of-bbbq-zeta-7?rq=1) etc. but they use galois theory, but I only know Field theory and am also trying to solve the question using only that.

Comment: Let $\alpha=\beta+\beta^{-1}$. Then ${\bf Q}(\alpha)$ has degree 3. There are also examples with degree 2.

Comment: @GerryMyerson so is my question wrong? Anyway would you considering giving an answer.

Comment: OK, I've given an answer – does it work for you?

Comment: Are you still here, Coherent?

Comment: @GerryMyerson In the linked questions, it's proved that there is no intermediate field between $Q$ and $Q(e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{7}})$ other than those two itself, so I am also waiting for a few other answers. If I find you answer helpful, I'll definitely accept it, you don't need to worry about it.I'm not a new member to the site.

Comment: I don't know what more you want answered. You've asked to show that ${\bf Q}(\alpha)$ is $K$, and I've shown that ${\bf Q}(\alpha)$ doesn't have to be $K$. What else are you hoping to see in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\beta=e^{2\pi i/7}$, let $K={\bf Q}(\beta)$, let $\alpha=\beta+\beta^{-1}$. Then $$\alpha^3=\beta^3+3\beta+3\beta^{-1}+\beta^{-3}=\beta^3+3\beta+3\beta^6+\beta^4$$ and $$\alpha^2=\beta^2+2+\beta^{-2}=\beta^2+2+\beta^5$$ [thanks to Robert Lewis for drawing my attention to a typo here, which I have corrected] so $$\alpha^3+\alpha^2-2\alpha-1=1+\beta+\beta^2+\beta^3+\beta^4+\beta^5+\beta^6=0$$ It's easily seen that $x^3+x^2-2x-1$ is irreducible over the rationals, so it is the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$, so ${\bf Q}(\alpha)$ is a proper subfield of $K$, of degree 3.

Similarly, one can show that $\gamma=\beta+\beta^2+\beta^4$ is of degree two over the rationals.

Comment: If $\alpha = \beta + \beta^{-1}$, does not $\alpha^2 = \beta^2 + \beta^{-1} + 2$? Where does $\alpha^2 = \beta^2 + 2\beta^{-1} + 2$ come from?